# Laugh at/with something

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

The meaning I would like to express is that one day something which was previously considered serious, or the very fact that it was considered serious, will seem funny.

Is it right to say "one day you will laugh at/with it", or is there any other suitable expression?

Comment: laugh at it, no doubt about it. Note: you can laugh at someone, not nice. Or you can laugh with them, nice. :)

Answer (score 1):

"in ten years we'll **look back on it** and laugh"  could make a direct referral to an incident

"**we'll look back and laugh**" without the 'on it' is the common idiom.

Here is a link to the [google Ngram for "look back and laugh"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=look%20back%20and%20laugh&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clook%20back%20and%20laugh%3B%2Cc0)

(I'm not sure what else to add but it was a bit too much an answer to put in a comment.)

Answer (score -1):

be **laughable**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/laughable)

> causing or deserving laughter

As in:

> One day it will be will **laughable**.
>   One day we shall have a good laugh (about something). (using the idiom)